# How do I raise 30k to keep my best friend in college?

Tags: college, crowdfunding

Today, my best friend texted me and said that he was going to drop out of college because he had been denied financial aid. He is very smart (1550+ SAT) and an incredible guy, but his parents have weird financials so that he is ineligible for need-based financial aid, even though he is broke without it. Our school doesn't offer merit-based aid. For him to stay in school next year, even with him working all summer, we need $30k, ten of which has to be paid by June. He is an international student, so lots of stuff is off the table, but he is also very popular. His girlfriend and I are willing to work like hell to help him pull this off.

Between people we know, we could probably raise $500 in the next week, but we have no idea where to go from there. Has anything like this worked before and how did they go about it?

Comment: Which options are "off the table" because he's an international student?

Comment: What is the major? If the major is one like CS or finance, there more options than say if it is English...

Comment: You should also consider whether the best financial decision is to remain at the current college. If you need to raise another $30k next year, that is substantially different from needing to raise the money only once.

Comment: "Our school doesn't offer merit-based aid" Find a school that does. There's no reason that a person with those test scores should have to pay for college.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems like spam.  Really, no merit based scholarships?  No options because they are an international student?  This is a plea for money not a real question.

Comment: @PeteB. surely because it is about OP's **friend and colleague**, and sending the friend to a different, distant college would **defeat the purpose, which is to keep a friend**. They could both go, but then OP would lose all other friends and possibly GF as well.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica That sounds like an interpersonal problem, not a personal finance problem.

Comment: Calling this spam seems a bit unfair, given that the author hasn't given any impression of trying to collect money from people here, such as contact details or any other way of paying.

Comment: Something's off here, or significant, important details were missed. If need based financial aid is even a question, then is the student a US resident/green card holder? Are their parents living/working in the US? A non resident international student doesn't qualify for federal or state aid in the first place, so the wording of that re: financials would be irrelevant. A legal resident, however, may have options.

Comment: To me, this is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Are you trying to ensure your friend's future success? Keep your friend in *a* college? Or are you trying to keep him *at your* college because you're friends? Despite some overlap, these goals are independent from one another, and before you can solve the problem you must know what problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: Also, you can only help your friend if he is more motivated to find a solution than you are.

Comment: You don't. This is a terrible idea. Don't waste your money on others, at least not like this.

Comment: @DStanley - lack of merit-based aid is not uncommon, particularly among highly selective schools. The assumption in their case is that *everyone* there is scholastically meritorious so need-based aid is all that's offered.

Comment: @BobJarvis-ReinstateMonica then change to a college that does. Not qualifying for need-based aid based on "weird financials" sounds like someone is hiding money or doesn't _want_ to pay for college. It's not (to me) a valid reason to ask for money from strangers.

Comment: Are you positive the message is real, not a scam?  Consider calling your friend to discuss directly.

Comment: @Criggie they shouldnt necessarily trust the friend either - they should get this information from an independent source, such as the university (the friend can give the university permission to discuss the matter with the OP).

Comment: @PeteB. Spam for what though? There is no link, no name, no nothing.

Comment: @Moo If his girlfriend is also going to get a second (third?) job to pull it off, well, it must be a fairly elaborate ruse.

Comment: @corsiKa or he could just be of poor character and seeing an opportunity to rid himself of a girlfriend, some friends and gain a boatload of money at the same time.

Answer (score 66):

Might be a better investment to go to a different country and study. The US prices for education are incredibly overpriced (having taught at both European universities and an Ivy league university in the US, I can tell that the education is not much different).

It is also easier to get admitted to European universities - the difficult part is to actually complete the studies.

Comment: This sounds like terrible advice. Yes it might be a good investment for SOME people. But there are costs associated with moving to a different state, let alone a different country. There are language barriers with moving to a different country. Even if some classes are taught in english, how will you fit in socially? Is every teenager prepared to live thousands of miles away from family and friends? Hey- move to Europe if you want to. Not the solution for everyone though.

Comment: @chevybow for an international student who is already far away from home, most of that is a non issue. most courses in western european countries are taught in english, or english is supported very heavily.

Comment: @chevybow Getting $30k of debts and having friends to beg for money isn't the solution for everyone either.

Comment: @chevybow the expensive part is housing, but there are a lot of international students all over Europe. Moreover, all master level classes where I teach are taught in English, and there are also a lot of undergraduate classes in English. 
In scandinavia where I am from, English is a non-issue. Also, I moved 400km within my country when i was 15 to go to high-school. Everything is possible with enough motivation.

Comment: Assessing the US education system based on one Ivy League university is a false generalization.  Yes, Ivy League schools are incredibly overpriced.  You can get the same education (but fewer rich friends) at a state university for a small fraction of the cost.

Comment: @BenVoigt I am sure you can, but $30k still sounds extremely expensive.

Comment: @PerAlexandersson: That's why the top-voted comment is to look at other schools.

Comment: How do you know they're in the US? I don't see a country mentioned anywhere.

Comment: @Clockwork US dollar currency, the fact that one needs to pay rules out most European countries, the price, the reference to SAT (only US schools require SAT for admittance, to my knowledge), the fact that the parents finances has any influence of the (adult) kid's right to aid...

Comment: @BenVoigt: Not sure what state schools you are talking about. Out-of-state tuition on many state schools is right up there with the Ivy league prices. In-state tuition can be cheaper but you need to qualify as a resident. They are certainly NOT a fraction. Or to be precise: "total cost of attendance". Some state schools have very low tuition but enormous chunk of mandatory fees.

Comment: @BenVoigt By international standards most US state schools are still extremely expensive.

Comment: @Cubic: According to the exchange rate, definitely.  According to purchasing power parity, things are much closer.

Comment: @BenVoigt Having lived and worked both in the US and several European countries, I can assure you that is not the case.

Comment: @Cubic: Most of the world is not Europe.

Comment: @PerAlexandersson There are plenty of European countries that charge tuition fees. But I agree with your overall point.

Answer (score 37):

1. He could speak with a financial aid counselor to make sure he understands *all* of his options, including whether there are any policies/petitions that could take into account his parents' "weird financials". Is his situation really so rare that no one has heard of it? Or can he learn about what the possible outcomes have been in similar cases?
2. While his school doesn't offer merit-based aid, he could apply for external merit scholarships. The school should have an office to advise on this.
3. He could apply for student loans.
4. He could try crowdfunding such as GoFundMe, especially if his story would be compelling to the public.
5. Rather than dropping out, he could take a leave of absence to have time to raise the money (e.g., by working) and resume his studies later.

Comment: "Rather than dropping out, he could take a leave of absence to have time to raise the money (e.g., by working) and resume his studies later." If he's an international student, it's possible that his visa is tied to his enrollment, and he might have limits on how much paid employment he's allowed to have each week.

Comment: "Middle class income but own a large illiquid asset." is a common enough problem for lots of families trying to qualify for aid even without the challenges of being international.

Comment: @Affe I think most people solve that with 3, "a loan".

Comment: @user3067860 Could easily be unable to take a loan - either because the illiquid asset isn't really worth what they have to claim it's worth, or because they are of a religion that doesn't permit borrowing, or ... lots of reasons that wouldn't work.  Not to say they shouldn't explore it, though.  I'd guess it's more likely a divorce and/or unwilling to support parent(s) that are causing the financials, though - that's by far the most common reason in my experience.

Answer (score 13):

Given his circumstances I would go to a community college for significantly cheaper, and accumulate as many transferable credits as possible. While at the same time working and saving up as much money as possible. After one or two years, transfer to the college of your choice and continue working to pay off tuition. Many if not all colleges offer some kind of deferred payment plan so the money made working during the year should be enough to pay for college.

I don't believe being an international student affects community college tuition, but he should check this for the specific college he chooses.

Comment: This is solid advice. Community College was an incredible experience for me. And it cost me 1/10 what a 4 year university would. OP didn't mention the friend's major, but it's easily possible they'll earn just as much with a 2 year CC degree as a 4 year Uni degree. This is definitely the case in software development (my field). Unless you're going into medicine, law, or some other high-earning field inaccessible without those credentials, spending $30k on education is just silly.

Answer (score 1):

Tell him to cut his losses and get out of college while he still can! What a waste of time. Get a specialized certificate from a industry authority and you'll make much more money and spend tens of thousands less on the education! What a gimmick this U.S. college system.
Here's a few examples of big money makers: rope access technician, security penetration testing, company GDPR/privacy officer...

Answer (score 0):

**Crowdfunding for education**

There is a crowdfunding site for individual goals, like Kickstarter. Common projects funded on it are for people's' education and healthcare. Take a look at some of the past projects and their marketing, and you might be able to replicate those successes.

https://www.gofundme.com/

Comment: Well, have a look at some of the success stories for education / college tuition fundraising. It is possible to get 2000 € to 3000 €, but I highly doubt people will pay 30.000$ per year.

Comment: @ThomasWeller Have to agree --- it's a bad investment.